# Wordpress Using Zip code customer shop find without woocommerce plugin

Tags: customization, json

How can i implement using zip code each and every single image we can add a zip code using search the customer shop. can you give me any suggestion. Using Zip Code and then give name of Dealer, address and phone number

Comment: Images are saved as 'attachment' post types, and you can save extra fields on them as post meta. However this sounds like an admin site change you want, and I'd guess address search plugins are mostly end-user facing, but I'd guess you could repurpose one to use for attachment field editing in the admin site. I don't know of anything that exists already though.

Comment: Actually I want to display data dynamically on every project page just like we display title, content, address using zipcode

Comment: Oh, so you want to take geolocation data from the image EXIF metadata and automatically do a Google Maps search for “dealers near latitude,longitude”? I suspect they won’t all find a result, or always find the right result, so you probably will need a way to override this.

Comment: Actually I want to display data dynamically on every page just like we display title, content, metas etc.

In short Data of each page should be displayed on that respective project only using zip code